# Display different item name using CSS

Tags: html, css, list

I have no control over the html cuz its hosted on the other server. If I want to use css to modify some of the list item, how should I do it?

For instance

the server side html:

```
<ol>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
<li>Orange Juice</li>
<li>Chocolate Milk</li>
<li>Espresso with hot foamy milk</li>
<li>Espresso diluted with hot water</li>
</ol>
```

And i want to use css to display the last two items as "Cappuccino" and "Americano".

Thanks.

Comment: CSS is just for styles, you should be changing the HTML if the content has changed. It shouldn't matter where it's hosted. Buck up and make the change

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's possible by rendering it using the `:after` pseudo class. But it's really really ugly. Only do this if you don't have any other alternative:

```
ol li:nth-child(5){
    color: #fff;           /* same color as the background to hide it */
    position:relative;
}    
ol li:nth-child(5):after{
    content: "Capuccino";
    display: block;
    color: #000;          /* your text color */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25Jw5/)

Comment: ;) spot on - I tried this and thought we might be able to add html entities but they show 'as-is'. +1 for taking the time to style it up to position the text correctly though. NOTE: This answer is only for educational purposes and should NOT be used in production...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the content of HTML tags via CSS.

You can hope doing so via JavaScript, and even then, you'll need to select the matching elements from the DOM, and replacing their `innerHTML` property.

---

Impossible with CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

The only hack I can think of is to use the property:

```
{display:none}
```

for each tag manuely.